# iOS In-App Purchases - Receipts validation

Tags: ios, swift2, in-app-purchase

I'm having a hard time understanding how things work with In-App Purchases on iOS. I'm developing an app in Swift2 for iOS9+ where users can subscribe to a Auto-Renewal subscription.

The subscription process works fine : I make the purchase, then send the receipt to my backend server to verify the receipt, and it returns the response back to my application. If the verification succeeds, I show a success page to the user.

The problem is that I have to check at every boot that the subscription is still valid. Here are my questions :

1. When do I have to refresh the receipt with the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` so that my backend receive the latest Receipt info? Doing so prompts the user for their iTunes login/password, pretty annoying. When testing on my device, at the first boot, there is no Receipt data, but a few seconds later, the receipt is available, without having requested a refresh or a restore... so it seems that somehow the Receipt get downloaded by iOS?!
2. If my subscription gets renewed, I post my Receipt to my backend and when validating with the iTunes API, I only see the initial purchase, not the renewed ones. So I guess I should ask to refresh the Receipt at every boot?
3. When restoring In-App Purchases (triggered manually with a button in my interface) with the `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()` function, does the Receipt gets refreshed at the same time? Let's say that a user gets a new device and installs my application, if I don't ask for the Receipt refresh, he could trigger the Restore Purchases button. Will the receipt be updated after the restore function has completed? If so, is it better to restore the purchases (doesn't prompt the user/password if already logged in App Store) instead of refreshing the Receipt, as it would achieve in the same result but without asking the password?

Many thing are not documented, I googled a lot and couldn't find clear information about these questions. I would really like to understand/know what is the correct workflow for this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't need to refresh the receipt if you are validating with Apple.  If you send any receipt to Apple you can then look at the `latest_receipt_info` entry in the response from Apple to determine the most recent renewals and whether they are active.

Comment: Have you read the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267)?

Comment: @Paulw11 It seems like this `latest_receipt_info` property has been removed, it doesn't appear in the response from the iTunes API. @rmaddy Yes, but couldn't find the answer to my questions.

Comment: It is definitely there.  My code is using it right now.  It isn't in the receipt you get from the receipt URL, it is in the JSON response that Apple sends you back in response to a receipt validation request

Comment: @Paulw11 My error indeed. The PHP script I was using was returning the `receipt` property instead of the whole object. Ok so I don't have to refresh the Receipt, but what if I switch to a new device, do I have to refresh the Receipt at the first boot?

Comment: If you can't fetch a local receipt then you can request a refresh. You should also provide a restore button

Comment: @Paulw11 In my case, on my subscription interface, I already have a Restore previous purchases button, but I'm wondering what's it useful for to restore transactions if I can simply refresh the Receipt (containing all the purchases)? My idea was to switch my restore code to simply do a Receipt refresh and then validate with my backend. Does it makes sense?

Comment: I like to have the button just so the user has some control as well; in case they connect to the network after the app has launched for example

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your help. Indeed Apple suggest to simply refresh the Receipt instead of restoring the purchases, is possible : `In most cases, all your app needs to do is refresh its receipt and deliver the products in its receipt. The refreshed receipt contains a record of the user’s purchases in this app, on this device or any other device. However, some apps need to take an alternate approach` as described here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html